# How to randomly select a character everytime it's needed

Tags: python, random

How do I randomly select a character from a string of characters every time I want it to be changed, for example:

```
import random

def user_input():
    chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    present = random.choice(chars)
    while True:
        print present
        to_eval = raw_input('Enter key: ')
        if to_eval == present:
            print 'Correct!'
            break
        else:
            # change the key and ask again

user_input()
```

Comment: Just overwrite present with ```random.choice(chars)``` in your empty else-clause.

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Do you want the user to continue to guess until successful, then create a new random value to guess?  Or just give him one chance before you change the mystery number?

Comment: @joelgoldstick Continue to guess until they have succeeded.

Comment: Then why would you put the code to change the mystery character in the code path that only executes if the user guesses *wrong*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import random

def user_input():
    chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    present = random.choice(chars)
    while True:
        print present
        to_eval = raw_input('Enter key: ')
        if to_eval == present:
            print 'Correct!'
            present = random.choice(chars)

user_input()
```

This will keep asking until correct.  Then pick a new value and continue to loop.  To end you would have to type ctl-c

Answer (score 0):

It think this is what you want:

```
import random

def user_input():
    while True:
        chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
        present = random.choice(chars)
        print present
        to_eval = raw_input('Enter key: ')
        if to_eval == present:
            print 'Correct!'
            break

user_input()
```

Answer (score 0):

you could play with [yield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do-in-python) to try simplify your code too:

```
import random

def guesses():
    chars = 'abcd..'
    while True:
        yield random.choice(chars) == raw_input('Enter Key: ').strip()

def play():
    for guess in guesses():
        if guess:
            print 'Correct!'
            break
```